# Need to read from the server using php file_get_function

Tags: php, curl, server, file-get-contents

I want to read the response from a server from another server on user request for which I am using php file_get_content method

as

```
<?php 
   set_time_limit(0) ;
   $url = "http://domain.com/function.php";

  $response = file_get_contents($url);
  echo $response;
?>
```

But in response I get an error as 
**Warning: file_get_contents(http://domain.com/function.php) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream:**

Also I have updated the php.ini and made active the [image]

Please let me know what steps I follow to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably be best off using cURL.

```
$ch = new curl_init('http://domain.com/function.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

[The php curl docs can be found here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)